# Bokeh customJS - creating new glyphs unachievable?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a blank figure in Bokeh, and I would like to add line glyphs to that figure, conditional on the Select widget that is chosen. This would select a dictionary of arrays, which would provide the X and Y values to draw for each line.

An example of the code would be

```
p = figure()

selector = Selector(value='foo', options=['foo','bar'])

data = {
    'foo':[{'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6], name='foo1'},
           {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6], name='foo2'}],
    'bar':[{'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6], name='bar1'},
           {'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[4,5,6], name='bar2'}]
}

callback = CustomJS(args={p=p, data=data, selector=selector}, code='''
    
    for (var element in data[selector.value]){
            var line = new Bokeh.Line({
                x:{ field : element["x"]},
                y:{ field : element["y"]}
            })
            p.add_glyph(line)
        }
'''

selector.js_on_change('value', callback)
show(p)
```

However, as far as I can see, there are two problems that are encountered with this approach.

1. The x and y parameters for Bokeh.Line do not accept arrays. Changing the field to 'value' only lets Bokeh.Line plot one value, and still does not accept arrays.
2. This produces a `TypeError` when a value is selected (foo or bar) which states `Bokeh.Line is not a constructor`

Have I missed something very basic here? Is there no straightforward way to draw new gylphs through CustomJS which doesn't involve drawing them all in advance, and the filtering out the ones you don't want?

Comment: This brings up the error `p.line()` is not a function.

Comment: You need to pass a `ColumnDataSource` with the data as a second argument to to `p.add_glyph`. The field specifications are references to columns in a CDS. All that said, a *much* better approach in general would be add all the glyphs up front and use the select callback to toggle their visibility as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks bigreddot, your suggestion (toggling the visibility) is what I ended up doing. However, I'm plotting >400 lines and potentially more in the future, so it seemed like a reasonable approach to just plot the ones I needed.